# eMMC ICs - what VCCQ (dual voltage): 1.70–1.95V; 2.7–3.6V means?

Tags: power-supply, vcc, emmc

I am struggling  to understand what `VCCQ (dual voltage): 1.70–1.95V; 2.7–3.6V` means.

Does it mean that it can be supplied by any of those voltages?

Some example models: SDINBDG4-8G-XI1, MTFC8GAM, MTFC16GAP, MTFC32GAP, MTFC64GAP, MTFC128GAP and many more.

None of those models have different versions for 1.8 or 3.3V volts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the chips will work at both voltage ranges, but it must be initialized according to which range you are going to use.

Comment: I do not see how to initialize it.

Comment: I am sure this info would be in the eMMC specs.